# How do I rotate a map marker in angular-leaflet-directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

My map markers are adorable little aeroplanes and I would like to be able to orientate them? If there a way to do this programmatically without creating multiple images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3:

```
transform: rotate(<angle>deg);
```

or

```
<element>.style.transform = "rotate(<angle>deg)";
```