# Rotate marker in angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rotation, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

EDIT: **I don't care on how to fix my code/why it's behaving like that, I just want to rotate a marker in angular-leaflet-directive, around its center.**

I'm aware of [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414750/how-do-i-rotate-a-map-marker-in-angular-leaflet-directive) but I have no idea on how to get the DOM element of every marker. The way that I'm creating markers, is

```
$rootScope.markers.push(
            {
                lng : 23.8404236,
                lat : 38.04595,
                icon: {
                    iconUrl : url,
                    iconSize: [30, 30]
                }
            }
        );
```

I also want to rotate them around the coordinates that they correspond to, not their tip (the top left most corner in Leaflet's terms).

I'm currently using [Marker.Rotate.js](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/tree/master/layer) but they are rotated around some arbitrary point as you can see here:
[image][image]

Their code is:

```
$rootScope.markers.push(
            {
                lng      : 23.8404236,
                lat      : 38.04595,
                icon     : {
                    iconUrl : 'misc/images/debug3.png',
                    iconSize: [30, 30]
                },
                iconAngle: 30
            }
        );
        $rootScope.markers.push(
            {
                lng : 23.8404236,
                lat : 38.04595,
                icon: {
                    iconUrl : url,
                    iconSize: [30, 30]
                }
            }
        );
        $rootScope.markers.push(
            {
                lng      : 23.8404236,
                lat      : 38.04595,
            }
        );
```

The original pic's size is 120x120 so it can be downscaled to 30x30. Also I'm not setting the anchor, because given size, it is automatically set to the middle ([15,15] I'm guessing) - even if I do set the anchor the result is the same.

I want the markers to rotate around their [15,15], not their bottom left corner or whatever other point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked the answer like so:

```
$rootScope.markers.push(
{
    icon   : {
        type      : 'div',
        className : 'marker-default',
        html      : '<img style="transform-origin: center 20px; transform: rotate('+rotation+'deg)" src="'+url+'">',
        iconAnchor: [12, 20]
    },
    lat      : parseFloat(DeviceData[i].Position.Y),
    lng      : parseFloat(DeviceData[i].Position.X),
    message  : "<div ng-include src=\"'templates/markerTemplate.html'\" ng-controller=\"markerBaseController\" data-deviceiterator=" + i.toString() + "></div>",
});
```

it's not pretty, but it works.